# Bash too many arguments error with `cd $VAR`, where $VAR is path name with escaped spaces

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I could not `cd` to a directory, whose path name contains escaped spaces, that is represented by a variable.

The following command does not work.

```
~$ VAR="/mnt/e/documents/my\ files"
~$ cd $VAR
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

However, when I use the path name as it is instead of assigning it to a variable, it works.

```
~$ cd /mnt/e/documents/my\ files
cd /mnt/e/documents/my files$
```

How to use cd with a variable as its argument, where the variable is a string with spaces that are escaped.

Comment: Always run your scripts through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and follow its advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

Remove the backslash in the middle of `my\ files`. You only need to escape that space when you're not quoting it.

Add quotes around `$VAR`: `cd "$VAR"`, otherwise it looks as though you are providing two parameters: "/mnt/e/documents/my" and "files"

Comment: and you shouldn't really be using all caps for your own variable name...